# Formula to count reoccurrences in a data set

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a data set of dates and locations that serves as a record of the location for each day of the year.

eg

| Date | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | London |
| 02/01/23 | London |
| 03/01/23 | Bristol |
| 04/01/23 | London |
| 05/01/23 | Manchester |
| 06/01/23 | London |
| 07/01/23 | London |
| 08/01/23 | Bristol |

I would like help with a formula that populates a third column that counts independent visits to each place.

eg

| Date | Location | Location# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | London | London1 |
| 02/01/23 | London | London1 |
| 03/01/23 | Bristol | Bristol1 |
| 04/01/23 | London | London2 |
| 05/01/23 | Manchester | Manchester1 |
| 06/01/23 | London | London3 |
| 07/01/23 | London | London3 |
| 08/01/23 | Bristol | Bristol2 |

How could I write this with a formula (happy to create additional column is it not possible to write into one formula)?

I have no idea where to start with this. Ideally, I want to avoid using an array.

Comment: Why London1 twice, but Bristol1 only once?

Comment: Think of the first two days as the first 'trip' to London (London1). And the third day as the first 'trip' to Bristol. As the table records more 'trips' the third column is updated to reflect which 'trip' that day is part of.

Comment: Still don't follow the logic - how do you know if any trip is to be classed as 1 when it is over two days?

Comment: @SolarMike It's the first trip to London, then the first to Bristol, then the second to London, then the first to Manchester, the third to London and the second to Bristol hence the numbers.

Comment: @Notus_Panda but could also be "the first trip to London, t then the second to London, then the first to Bristol, then the first to Manchester, the third to London and the second to Bristol hence the numbers... No real way of knowing from the data - need another column of info.

Comment: @SolarMike The OP explained it in words, it's their logic and their choice of constructing their data in that manner. Not sure why there's a discussion about that..

Comment: @Notus_Panda because it is still not explained in the original question, where it SHOULD be clearly explained. As you are well aware, comments are not meant for crucial information...

Comment: I think it's clear that he wants a running counter of locations, where if the location doesn't change from the previous occurance, the counter should not update. So if 3 day in a row the visit would be the same location, than the cummulative counter remains the same. If another location is inbetween, the counter should update:

`=LET(L,B2:B9,L&MMULT((TOROW(L)=L)*(TOROW(N(L<>INDEX(B:B,ROW(L)-1,0)))=1)*(TOROW(ROW(L))<=(ROW(L))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(L),,,0)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution (Sheets).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(l,B2:B,
       r,ROW(l),
       u,IF(l=OFFSET(l,-1,,ROWS(l)),,l),
       IF(l="",,l&SCAN(,COUNTIFS(u,u,r,"<="&r),LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v,v,a))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(
    φ,B2:B9,
    φ&TAKE(
        SORT(UNIQUE(REDUCE("",φ,LAMBDA(δ,ε,
        LET(τ,FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(φ)),φ=ε),
        DROP(VSTACK(δ,HSTACK(τ,SCAN(0,τ,
        LAMBDA(κ,λ,IF(λ=1,1,IF(INDEX(φ,λ)=INDEX(φ,λ-1),κ,κ+1)))))),1)))))),,-1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather have correct answers under a question so I deleted my previous one (to not confuse future people having the same issue), rightly stated as wrong by Jos/OP. My second answer should be an improvement to it:

Excel:

> =LET(lOccur,LOOKUP(1,0/FIND(B2,$C$1:C1),$C$1:C1),lNum,--RIGHT(lOccur,LEN(lOccur)-LEN(B2)),IF(B2=B1,C1,IF(ISERROR(lOccur),B2&"1",B2&lNum+1)))

[image]

No clue how to make this a spill formula this time around though, I'm getting either wrong results or circular reference..

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach (**for Gsheets**);
this goes into `Cell_C2` and then **drag-it-down***

```js
=map(B2,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,Σ&countif(map(B$2:Σ,lambda(Λ,if(Λ=iferror(offset(Λ,-1,)),,Λ))),Σ))))
```

[image]

- *Jus in case you wish to use the above formula `array-style`, replace the starting `B2` part into `B2:B`*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (Sheets)

```
=MAP(B2:B,LAMBDA(_,IF(_="",,_&COUNTIFS(B2:_,_,MAP(B2:_,LAMBDA(_,N(_=OFFSET(_,-1,)))),0))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about this in one formula:

```
B2&COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)*COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Also doesn't match the OP's expected results.

Comment: @JosWoolley not sure I believe his results... see my comments above.